# Policy to allow user to enumerate accounts only within his own OU in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

Is it possible to define a policy which restricts a user to enumerate only accounts in his own OU?

For example lets consider a domain Contosos and OUs Sales and HR.The Sales OU has two users A and B and the HR OU has users C and D.

Is it possible to define a policy so that A can only enumerate accounts A and B and C can only enumerate C and D and not the accounts not in their OU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do That!

But, you can create a group for each OU and put the ou users inside the group. Than you can change the permission on every other OU to deny this group the "list content" permission. I don't think that there is a way to configure this without scripting. But as the rule is simple it can be scripted.

That said. I would advise you not to dare and change the active directory default permission without having a dedicated group of experts on this specific subject. You can quite easily render your network useless with just a few clicks. And even if you don't, there is a chance that programs that have expectation from active directory security ( without even realizing this ) will suffer from subtle errors.

So the rule is. If you have to ask, don't do it. if you need to become an expert, then:

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=active+directory+permission+site:microsoft.com&btnG=Search

**Update:** The "If you need to ask" rule refers to asking on a public site like this. Where non-experts, like me, can give you potentially misleading information, as mine can be( I hope not, but...). I am not sure that your requirement don't have a simple solution. 
 But as far as I know, this is a path that burned more than few brave souls.

Answer (score 0):

Good point! 
I myself have no idea about how to do it, however Igal Serban's answer touched me. He is right, in public forum, if you take immature suggestions you will pay much for it. I was bite for such reason once.

Read some books or consult some experts!